# Difference between 'baiser' and 'foutre'

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, jurons

Both words could roughly translate to 'fuck' in English. I know that 'baiser' could imply 'fuck' in the context of sexual relations but I believe 'foutre' does the same too. Is there any difference between the two, or are they just one of the many swear words in the language?

Comment: À première vue, on ne semble pas avoir parlé nulle part d'une expression fort simple comme _tu vas tout foutre en l'air_, dans le sens de faire rater. On ne peut y substituer _baiser_ dans ce genre de contexte.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Foutre est une terme vulgaire, mais qui n'est plus employé au sens de *faire l'amourr*. On le rencontre dans l'expression *se faire foutre* (pour *se faire voir*), mais aussi au sens de *faire*, pour lequel la conjugaison complète est possible, contrairement à ce qu'affirme Charlie:

> Qu'est-ce que tu fous ici?
>
> Je ne sais pas ce que vous foutez toute la journée, mais...

Il y a aussi l'expression *n'être pas foutu de*, qui signifier "manquer de compétence ou de volonté pour accompli une tâche plutôt simple":

> Vos employés ne sont pas foutus de régler le problème.

Comment: Entièrement d'accord, foutre peut très bien se conjuguer. On dit d'ailleurs `Fous le camp !`, qui peut signifier "Dégage" (langage très familier)

Comment: Je me fous de toutes ces expressions vulgaires!

Comment: Aussi "baiser" peut vouloir dire embrasser. Comme dans l'expression baiser la main par exemple.

Comment: @Kii Le sens "embrasser" a été complètement évacué en français contemporain. Il est au mieux vieilli, au pire obsolète et ne se rencontre plus que dans des expression comme  celle que tu cites. Personne n'oserait l'employer sérieusement dans ce sens sauf par ironie.

Answer (score 3):

Although « foutre » translates to the "F-word" in many vulgar expressions that aren’t at all sexual in nature (even « va te faire foutre » = "go F^^K/'do’ yourself" isn’t really sexual), I have heard it used in one phrase that is vulgar as well as sexual : « *fous-moi ça là » = "stick that thing right here [in me, baby]," but even here, the « fous » in « fous-moi » doesn’t mean the “F-word,” but rather « mettre » = “put”/“place”/”stick”/(insert?).
*(NB: Replace « fous-moi » with « foutez-moi » in situations where added respect is due or when orgies are involved)

Comment: So basically in this sense 'foutre' would mean penetrate?

Comment: Such a command will most likely lead to penetration, so perhaps you could translate it by "penetrate me WITH that thing, baby" instead of "stick that thing IN me, baby," but the "mettre"/"put" sense of "foutre" is more transitive than the intransitive "penetrate" & that's the only thing that causes me to hesitate a bit to agree completely with your good observation. Maybe "drill" would help resolve the transitive/intransitive issue I'm having while still maintaining the idea of penetration: "drill that thing in me, baby" or just "Drill baby drill!" for short! (what a topic, eh?)@user3182445

Comment: Yeah lol, I never thought I'd be discussing this sort of thing in such detail :D

Comment: Lol "foutez-moi"

Answer (score 1):

Foutre also means "cum"... it's rather vulgar, oui.

But "foutre" meaning "cum" was used in the late 12th century and didn't have at that time a vulgar connotation, it just meant "sperm" or "sperme" in French.

Comment: The Kama Foutre?

Answer (score 0):

'Foutre' is only used in the expression 'Va te faire foutre' ('Go fuck yourself'). 
You never conjugate it, or use it in the same way than 'baiser'.

It may also be used as a noun, as a (vulgar) synonym to 'sperm'.

Comment: @Circeus: you're right, you can conjugate 'foutre' when it means 'faire'.  I forgot to specify: you never conjugate 'foutre' when it means 'baiser'/'faire l'amour'.